# Magento send outgoing email to specific email address for testing

Tags: email, magento, development-environment, outgoing-mail

Is there an Admin Settings where i can set all the outgoing email to a specific email address.

The reason is in my development of Magento, i am using db from production and there are email addresses from real users which i do not want to acccidentaly send a message to them while im developing..

For example in subscribers, i want to send a newsletter but all emails should go to the email address i will set..

If no admin settings, i have no choice but to create migration script and update related tables that contains the email addresses..

Magento experts, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the admin settings for this.  You are making a wise move though, having live customer information in a dev site can be dangerous.  It's also a risk for the business, the customer details can be valuable so you really don't want them kicking around in a dev database at all imo.

There's a great set of tools for managing Magento from the command line

https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

Deleting the live customers and replacing them with dummies is one of the many options you've got;

https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#user-content-delete-customers

https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#user-content-generate-dummy-customers

So to delete all your live customers **in the dev site** you'd do;

```
php n98-magerun.phar customer:delete --all
```

from the command line once you've followed the instructions and downloaded the script to your Magento root.